# ViewController transition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, transition

I have code:

```
ListViewController * listViewController = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListViewController" bundle:nil];    

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self viewWillDisappear:YES];
[listViewController viewWillAppear:YES];

self.view.hidden = YES;
listViewController.view.hidden = NO;


[self viewDidDisappear:YES];
[listViewController viewDidAppear:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But it does not works, and listViewController does not displayed( Please, somebody can tell me the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
UIViewAnimationOptions ops = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight;
NSArray *temp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NameOfNib" owner:self options:nil];
UIView* newView = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] view];
[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:newView duration:1.5 options:ops completion:nil];
self.view = newView; //Lets you control the new view from the current controller (you might want to save a reference to the old one if you need to change back)
```

**As meronix said, non-block based animation is discouraged by Apple for the newer iOS versions.** The above method is the "approved" way to do it.

Just so you know, the `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidDisappear`, and similar methods aren't methods that YOU call to make the view do things. They're called automatically when these things happen.

Your code had a few misunderstandings; I've commented on them below

```
//This looks fine (depending on what is in the nib)
ListViewController * listViewController = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListViewController" bundle:nil]; 

//Normally I use these to move things around, not change the view
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];

[self viewWillDisappear:YES]; //These two methods aren't things that you call
[listViewController viewWillAppear:YES];

self.view.hidden = YES; //If you're flipping or otherwise moving a view out of 
listViewController.view.hidden = NO; //sight then you don't need to hide/unhide views

[self viewDidDisappear:YES]; //Same as above, you don't call these
[listViewController viewDidAppear:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!!) I still working with this problem) I'm new in objective-c((

Comment: Check out http://www.raywenderlich.com/ if you need some tutorials. They come highly recommended by pretty much everyone on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary code and just write this ...

```
ListViewController * listViewController = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListViewController" bundle:nil];    
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self.view addSubview:listViewController.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: When I used this code my current view (It's map view) only spinning on the spot..(( I need to change my current View (IBOutlet MKMapView * map) to listView.

Comment: it will flip listViewController.view you can flip any view just replace the listViewcontroller.view to your view. Because in your question you just ask for fliping.

Answer (score 0):

it cannot work!

you just create and allocate a UIViewController, but never push it on any stacks, or add its view to a visible view.

when you set listViewController.view.hidden to no, you are not magically showing it on screen: you need to add its view to a view (or window) which is already on screen...

ps beginAnimation is deprecated: use blocks animation instead...

Comment: `beginAnimations` isn't deprecated... I think it's just discouraged.

Comment: no, you are, right, apple just says: "Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead." and: "In iOS 4 and later, use the block-based animation methods. (Recommended)"

Comment: Okay, I was concerned and had to check because some of my older apps use `beginAnimations` and I didn't want to get screwed by iOS 6. Also, you'll see that my answer does recommend a block-based approach.

Comment: :-)  - as i said, you are right, recommended just means that soon or later apple will sign it as depreciated, maybe in a far future (let's hope that)... anyway, i loved the beginAnimation methods, but just 'couse i was used to them... then i forced myself to use block, and i love them now...

Comment: I'm just a beginner and would like to talk with an experienced developer)

Comment: meronix can you give me your Skype or Facebook link?

Comment: sorry man, i'm a bit busy at the moment, anyway, your error is not in animation, you just didn't add the controller.view to a visible view...

Comment: I do not about this problem!) I just asked for communication! :) Anyway thanks for help!!!)